# Xamarin.Forms: How to bind Dictionary to GridView

Tags: xaml, gridview, xamarin.forms

I have a `Dictionary<Datetime, List<Item>>` and I want to populate the dictionary in a GridView. I would like to show data as following:

--------------------------------------  
Datetime1
--------------------------------------
   item1.prop1          item1.prop2
   item2.prop1          item2.prop2
--------------------------------------  
Datetime2
--------------------------------------
   item3.prop1          item3.prop2
   item4.prop1          item4.prop2
   item5.prop1          item5.prop2

Is the GridView the correct control? How can I group the data by the key of a Dictionary?

Comment: I would use a grouped ListView

Comment: Ok I am going to check the grouped ListView

Comment: It works with grouped ListView